# Kafka old consumer rebalance issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In our system we're using an older version of kafka (0.9.0.1) and the old scala consumer API in a tomcat application.
Everything works fine most of the time, but sometimes when the servers where the consumers run are heavily utilised by some other tasks in the app then the consumers become unresponsive which triggers as expected a rebalance and that consumer is removed from its partitions and other consumers are used.

My question is if there is an easy way for the consumer to re-register itself when it comes back up?

I know that the old consumers store the partition consumer details in Zookeeper and was thinking we could have a task that would periodically check if our consumer is registered there and restart the consumer if not, but I'm not sure what exactly we should check there. Can anyone point me to some documentation about the data stored in zookeeper by kafka (haven't found anything in the official documentation sadly :( )?

Comment: You could use Zookeeper shell (or exhibitor), or other browser to read Zookeeper data yourself

Comment: kafka do rebalance for you, why do you want to do it manually again ?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, that is what I was thinking of doing, but was hoping that there was a more kafka way of doing this.

Comment: @Deadpool yes, kafka does the rebalancing. But my issue is as follows: 
- I have a topic consumed by server1 and server2
- server1 goes down or is overworked so it can't consume messages, kafka rebalances and only server2 consumes the topic
- server1 becomes available again but kafka doesn't recognise this and won't rebalance. This is my issue, how to make kafka rebalance and add server1 to the consumer (without needing to manually do anything -right now I need to figure out this has happened and restart the server manually-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is fixed assignments, and that consumer groups never rebalance. If there was a way to disable automatic consumer rebalancing in the old Scala client, or maybe even increase the rebalance timeout to a much higher value, that could also work, but I couldn't find how to do that with the old Scala consumer.

However, it is possible to assign fixed topic/partitions when using the newer Java consumers, also available in that same 0.9 kafka version.   Look for `Subscribing To Specific Partitions` in the latest Javadocs:

https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

```
Subscribing To Specific Partitions
   In the previous examples we subscribed to the topics we were interested in and 
   let Kafka give our particular process a fair share of the partitions for those topics. 
   This provides a simple load balancing mechanism so multiple instances of our program 
   can divided up the work of processing records.

   In this mode the consumer will just get the partitions it subscribes to 
   and if the consumer instance fails no attempt will be made to 
   rebalance partitions to other instances.
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, think there is a way to do this on the kafka brokers themselves so I could still use our current implementation, might try this as well.
There is only the issue that this way if a server becomes unavailable for any reason its partitions would stop being consumed (no rebalancing in this setup).